# Eclipse Indigo cannot import maven android that builds OK on command line

Tags: android, m2eclipse, eclipse-indigo, android-maven-plugin

I created a maven android project from the command line using this archetype:

```
19: remote -> android-quickstart (-)
```

I can call "mvn install" on it with success.

When I try to import the same project into Eclipse Indigo, I see this:

> No marketplace entries found to handle maven-android-plugin:2.8.3:generate-sources in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

and this:

> No marketplace entries found to handle maven-android-plugin:2.8.3:unpack in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

Note that there is no "Help" button here.

If I *Resolve Later* on these, the build fails with this:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:maven-android-plugin:2.8.3:generate-sources (execution: default-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)  pom.xml /t3 line 22 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

(and an additional error for the unpack phase)

I'll give my complete install list in a moment, but I noticed this plugin in Eclipse.  I think this shouldn't be there(?), since Indigo has M2E built in...

**- SonaType, Inc. Maven Integration for Eclipse 0.13.0**

Maybe I installed it by accident?

Anyway, here's the rest of my deal:

- Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
- Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 12:31:09-0500)
- Java version: 1.6.0_26, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
- Android Development Toolkit 11.0.0v201105251008-128486
- Eclipse Version: Indigo Release - Build id:
  20110615-0604

Comment: Went back to see if all the plugins were properly installed and found that m2eclipse-android-integration was missing. I got this error on install: **Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Android Development Tools 0.2.5 (com.googlecode.eclipse.m2e.android.feature.feature.group 0.2.5)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Android Development Tools 0.2.5 com.googlecode.eclipse.m2e.android.feature.feature.group 0.2.5) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse 0.12.0' but it could not be found**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thilo-Alexander Ginkel has it right: m2eclipse-android-integration just doesn't work with Indigo Java.  I followed this link, http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3b463cf80edc41e3, and someone suggested installing Indigo J2EE   which *does not* come with Maven integration.  Thus, to get m2Eclipse, Android, and m2Eclipse-Android-Integration it was effectively the same as Helios...you just install everything yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the m2e Android integration plugin is incompatible with the current m2e plugin release. For details, see: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/issues/detail?id=57

You may try building the plugin from source as the incompatibility has already been fixed on source-level (at least that's what I am trying to do right now).

**Edit:** Manually building m2eclipse-android-integration seems to be a little tricky, but I prepared some detailed information how to get the plugin running under Eclipse Helios (did not test Indigo) by installing an older plugin version: http://www.tgbyte.de/en/2011/07/building-android-maven-projects-with-eclipse/

Comment: Agreed.  Here is another link with a little more detail: http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3b463cf80edc41e3

Answer (score 1):

As Thilo-Alexandar says, the Maven Android Integration plugin is incompatible with the new m2e plugin release due to the move from Sonatype to eclipse, which required a full package re-name breaking all previous code.

A compatible version of the plugin will be released as soon as issue 23 is resolved:

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/issues/detail?id=23