# Eclipse Maven Jetty

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven, jetty, exec

I try to download projects http://svn.codehaus.org/jetty from SVN
but received this error:

```
No marketplace entries found to handle Execution exec-plugin-doc, 
in modules/jspc-maven-plugin/pom.xml in Eclipse.
```

What doesn't mean marketplace? May be I doesn't correct install Eclipse or SVN connectors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited info in the question, it looks like a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526741/eclipse-indigo-cannot-import-maven-android-that-builds-ok-on-command-line).  If so, you may want to try with an older version of Eclipse.